# How to add and change value in datagrid depending on the value on combox?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to make a grading system with C# winform and Linq but i am stuck with this..I am not sure if i did it right.. 
In the combo box, I have the data 'Class Standing, Performance Task and Major Exam'. When i select 'Class Standing' it should be able show 'Seatwork' and 'Assignment' in the Datagridview as what is in my database and if I select 'Performance Task' it should show 'Oral Participation' and 'Project'

Comment: The question is too broad for SO. Be aware that you should show your effort ! Also write what si this asp.net webforms or winforms. Whatever the main way you can do it is to Rebind the DataGrid on Combo box change value.

Comment: @mybirthname Sorry my bad.. I edited my question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)//Class Standing
        {
            //clear DataGridView
            //load data from database to dataGridView1
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1) //Performance Task
        {
            //clear DataGridView
            //load data from database to dataGridView1
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2) //Major Exam
        {
            //clear DataGridView
            //load data from database to dataGridView1
        }
    }
```

I hope it will be useful for you